# FirebaseMessaging without using google-services.json to support multiple projects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am aware of the ability to create a named `FirebaseApp` instance with custom options for use with, for example, `FirebaseDatabase`, but I specifically need the ability to use `FirebaseMessagaging` against different (determined at runtime) Firebase projects.

The problem I have is that `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()` doesn't support the name argument.

Is this in any way possible?

The reason I need to support separate projects is that our client connects to different customers server, so each customer will have their own firebase account and be generating their own notifications.

If it is not possible, is there any way to isolate one customer from another, so they can't possibly send notifications to another customer's device (assuming they could obtain a valid target device token in some way)?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/rF8y-d4MtdI/y_FOflzvBQAJ (correct link this time)

Answer (score 4):

[The Firebase Blog contains a post about this exact issue](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html), and provides a guide for how to handle it.

The blog post describes two steps:

1. Disable FirebaseInitProvider

Add this to the AndroidManifest.xml to disable the default initialization code:

```
<provider
  android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
  tools:node="remove"
  />
```

2. Call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context, FirebaseOptions)

As soon as you have the necessary configuration ready, initialize Firebase on your own with:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
  .setApiKey("your_api_key")
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
  .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

The [Google Services Plugin documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) describes how to get the values you need from the JSON:

`{YOUR_CLIENT}` is the `client` object that contains a `client_info/android_client_info/package_name` that matches your package name (application id).

google_app_id: `{YOUR_CLIENT}/client_info/mobilesdk_app_id`

gcm_defaultSenderId: `project_info/project_number`

default_web_client_id: `{YOUR_CLIENT}/oauth_client/client_id (client_type == 3)`

ga_trackingId: `{YOUR_CLIENT}/services/analytics-service/analytics_property/tracking_id`

firebase_database_url: `project_info/firebase_url`

google_api_key: `{YOUR_CLIENT}/api_key/current_key`

google_crash_reporting_api_key: `{YOUR_CLIENT}/api_key/current_key`

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I realized this shortly after posting, and started compiling a summary of the guide provided in the link. The answer has now been edited to contain more useful information.

Comment: thanks! Comment deleted; Unfortunately the flag went through, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

To allow a single client to receive messages from multiple senders you can use the [FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(A_SENDER_ID, "FCM")](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. So there is no need to have retrieve multiple Messaging instances, to manage multiple senders.

Once the message arrives you can filter on the `from` field of the `RemoteMessage` object that is passed via the `onMessageReceived` callback.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to `FirebaseMessaging` class, you'll see there's a **package private `getInstance`** which takes a `firebaseApp`. Also you'll see `getInstance()` is also using that with the default firebase app as the parameter. You can get it by reflection.

```kotlin
val firebaseApp = buildFirebaseApp()

val method = FirebaseMessaging::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance", FirebaseApp::class.java)
// Set the non-public accessible if security allowed
method.isAccessible = true
val fcmMessaging = method.invoke(null, firebaseApp) as FirebaseMessaging
```